# Float array as parameter to unmanaged code is always null

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm working on a C# wrapper for a C library. One of the functions fills an array of floats, having a signature as such:

```
STATUS fillArray(float **floatArray, int *count) {...}
```

On the C# side, I have the function declared as:

```
[DllImport (myDLL)]
public static unsafe extern STATUS fillArray(float **floatArray, int *count);
```

When used, I call it using

```
unsafe {
    float *floatArray;
    int count;
    fillArray(&floatArray, &count);
}
```

Thing is, `count` is passed perfectly, but `floatArray` is always `null`. If I call the function from C code, it works as intended (tried it just to see that it's implementation didn't have any issues).

I've also tried to go the IntPtr with an out attribute route, but that didn't work either.

EDIT:
Here is the function body:

```
STATUS fillArray(float **vertexArray, UINT32 *vertexCount) {

static float g_vertexData[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
};

*vertexArray = g_vertexData;

*vertexCount = 6;

return STATUS_OK;
}
```

Test C code, like I said, is identical:

```
float *vArray;
int count;
fillArray(&vArray, &count);
```

This was compiled using clang 900.0.37 as mac bundle, with the C# code running on the Mono 5.4.0.201 runtime. Don't know what else to note here.

Comment: Does `fillArray` actually allocate the space for the array?  I would expect, from your snippet here, that you are expected to pass in an already allocated array with count being the size of the array OR you are expected to call the function twice, the first time passing in null so that you get the count and then you allocate the array and call it again with a pre-allocated array of the appropriate size. It may be helpful if you can show the code for how you call it in C where it is working.

Comment: Yes, `fillArray` allocates the memory for the array, not just writes to it, hence the double pointer. In plain C, after the function call `floatArray` would be populated with the first address of an array generated by the function and `count` would contain the array size.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)` attribute for the float** parameter? Also, as a side note, if the memory is being allocated via malloc in the unmanaged code, you will need to provide a function from the unmanaged code to free it. There is no way to free malloc'd memory from managed code.

Comment: I believe that would not work, as `UnmanagedType.LPArray` is a pointer to the first element of an array... effectively a `float *`. I need a double pointer. Also, I am aware of the need to free the malloc'd memory from managed code, but that is a separate issue.

Comment: Can you show your C test code

Comment: My C code is identical to the “unsafe” part in the question. Works fine there. In the meantime I’ve reached a solution by wrapping everything inside a `struct` and sending that as `ref MyStruct` to the C code, which fills it with the pointer to the first element and the count. I know allocating memory on the C side of things seems like a no-no, but it’s quite common in my line of work and it seems only natural in this case, where the data is generated in the C part and I have no idea about the size of it. Having it deallocated back there is a trivial matter (in my case at least).

Comment: Still, I’d wish people would give a hint of an explanation though before downvoting.

Comment: You think that your C code is identical, but we only have your word for it. It would be simple to solve if you'd provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I’m away from my laptop and it was difficult to type that on the phone. Still, it’s only 3 lines of code. Truly identical.

Comment: You say that, but that is not at all clear. For instance, the code in the question makes it look like there is a calling convention mismatch. As you say, the code in the question should work perfectly, if things are as you present them. If it doesn't there is something else going on. If you can make a [mcve] I am quite sure I can identify the problem.

Comment: I would default to @DavidHeffernan here, but I think this should have worked if you added the MarshalAs(LPArray) and marked it as a `ref`, which is in essence the double pointer.  I did not downvote the question, although I have considered it as I feel it is far less clear than you are claiming. If it was clear there would not be this amount of commenting asking for clarification and repeatedly asking for an MCVE.

Comment: @pstrjds No, that won't work

Comment: I understand your point @DavidHeffernan I’ll add details as soon as I get to my computer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure there is a simple explanation

Comment: Added some more code and info. If there's anything else you'd want to know, please let me know. Like I said, I found a solution for my issue, by wrapping everything in a struct, but I'd like to understand why this doesn't work also. A calling convention seems issue seems plausible, although, from what I read, there wasn't any need to specify any convention on my platform (Mac/Linux)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - That is why I defaulted to you :)

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, I cannot reproduce what you describe on my platform, which is Windows.

I have this function in a DLL:

```c
__declspec(dllexport) int fillArray(float **vertexArray, int *vertexCount)
{
    static float g_vertexData[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    *vertexArray = g_vertexData;
    *vertexCount = 6;
    return 0;
}
```

This is consumed by this C# code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"Win32Project1.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static unsafe extern int fillArray(float** floatArray, int* count);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                float* floatArray;
                int count;
                if (fillArray(&floatArray, &count) == 0)
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                        Console.WriteLine(floatArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
0
0
0
1
0
0
```

Note that I included a calling convention which is necessary for a 32 bit Windows program, but not necessary on your platform.

I think it likely that the code you have posted is not actually the code that you have been running. The code as posted in your question is correct.

Comment: I had to redact some details unfortunately, but nothing that would impact the output (just names and some extra vars). This is running through Unity though and the Mono runtime, so maybe it’s a bug with Mono...

Comment: I very much doubt that. I suspect that the redaction could be a problem. You can use my code now as a test bed to prove to yourself that Mono is fine. If you take my code and it runs fine on your system then you know the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, but I think I need to remove the calling convention for my platform. In any case, I’ll give it a shot when I have a bit of time

Comment: Yeah, remove that. Not that it really matters, because `cdecl` is what you want.

Answer (score -2):

Why not do it correctly as managed memory?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum STATUS : int //make sure correct size
        {
            // add items
        }

        [DllImport("myDLL")]
        public static extern STATUS fillArray(IntPtr floatArrayPtr, IntPtr countPtr);

        const int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 100;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count = MAX_ARRAY_SIZE;
            IntPtr arrayPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(MAX_ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float));
            IntPtr countPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(count, countPtr, true);

            STATUS status = fillArray(arrayPtr, countPtr);

            float[] floatArray = new float[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
            Marshal.Copy(arrayPtr, floatArray, 0, count);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(arrayPtr);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(countPtr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. The caller allocates the array, hence the double pointer, `float**`. This code matches a single pointer, `float*`. The handling of count is equally broken.

Comment: Without seeing the c++ code you cannot tell if the code is using a point to a single array or a double array.  Since Count was a pointer I assumed it was a single pointer along with the OPs description : "One of the functions fills an array of floats"

Comment: The question clearly declares the first parameter as `float**`. The comments clarify that it is a pointer to an array that is allocated by the callee.

Comment: But count isn't usually a pointer.  Besides the Ops in his unsafe structure used :     float *floatArray;

Comment: This is the signature of the function that is being called: `STATUS fillArray(float **floatArray, int *count) {...}` The array is `float*`, but the parameter is `float**` because the callee creates the array and returns it. The caller passes the address of a `float*` variable. Exactly what the C# code does.  The count is an `int`, but the parameter is `int*` because the caller returns the count in the variable supplied by the caller. So the caller passes the address of an `int` variable.  Exactly what the C# code does.

Comment: How can the callee allocate an array without causing a memory leak?  I've written applications when the callee allocated memory using the windows allocation function, but then I knew to release the memory in my calling code.  But without explicit documentation stating to release memory it is dangerous.

Comment: That's a fair point, but one that the asker is aware of. He states in comments, *"Also, I am aware of the need to free the malloc'd memory from managed code, but that is a separate issue."* The unmanaged DLL would need to export a deallocator. Usually it is better to have the caller allocate, but sometimes not. Specifically when the size of the array cannot be known until it has been created.

Comment: Having said all of that, your obsession with using `IntPtr` and manual allocation is bizarre. Suppose that the function required caller to allocate and pass the size of the allocated array. Then the C# could look like this: `static extern int foo(float[] arr, ref int count);` The `count` arg has the allocated length on entry, and the number of elements actually populated on exit. The return value gives a status code, e.g. non-zero for an error. Your answers always opt for manual marshaling which is needlessly complex. And you always do it wrong in any case! As you do here.

Comment: I just follow the sample code at www.pinvoke.net and use similar methods to answer my postings.

Comment: The problem is that your pinvoke answers are always wrong. Every single time. You really do need to have some experience with doing pinvoke. It's not enough just to crib stuff from pinvoke.net (a notoriously low quality site FWIW) without the knowledge that comes from practical experience. It must be frustrating for you to have every pinvoke answer of yours criticised but the lesson to take away is that you are getting it wrong. It may sound immodest, but I do think that I know a little on this subject: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pinvoke/topusers

Comment: Of course, that is possible. But it seems that the voters think otherwise. You can lead a horse to water, .....

Comment: Your the one who keeps on giving me negative points.  Don't blame other voters when your the one.

Comment: Er, you have two down votes here. And I wasn't actually talking about votes on your answers in my previous comment, since you had moved on to discussing my answers.

Comment: Well, I can only state my point of view on why this does not apply to my use case: this needs to be efficient, as I will be handling larger sets of data in a performance sensitive system, so copying the array through the marshaller kind of defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: @CatalinM Manual marshalling isn't necessarily any less efficient. That's not the problem here. The problem here is that the code in the answer is bogus. As far as efficiency goes, your current design has its problems. As it stands you are likely to need to copy from the unmanaged array to a managed array. That's not efficient.

Comment: You could write c++ managed code to do the copying : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0adb9zxe.aspx.

Comment: In the end, I still need a copy of that data in a managed array of objects, but that requires some parsing which makes it unavoidable. What I needed was to avoid another copy besides that.

Comment: @jdweng this needs to be portable code. If I understand that correctly, it relies on MS specific stuff.

Comment: No need for managed C++ here, this is trivial enough from C#, if you actually know what you are doing, which jdweng plainly does not.

Comment: David : the issue is performance.  Yes it can be done in c#, but it will be slowly in c# than c++.

Comment: @jdweng No it won't. You've already made it clear in the comments above that you have no experience of this. Your answer makes it clear that you don't understand the code in the question, or indeed the code in your answer. You need to concentrate on the subject matters where you have experience and knowledge. And you need to deal with your pride.

Comment: Where did I say that I had no experience in this.  That is a very vague response.

Comment: *"I just follow the sample code at www.pinvoke.net and use similar methods to answer my postings."* If you ever tried to run any of the code you'd observe that it doesn't work. You are aware that the code in this answer doesn't work I presume?

Comment: Do you really know that it doesn't.  As you previously stated that the code on www.pinvoke.net doesn't work when I've used the code lots of times and it does work.

Comment: I know the code doesn't work. You haven't run it have you?

Comment: Here's what happens when you do try to run it. It throws `ArgumentNullException` at the call to `StuctureToPtr`, with additional information "Value cannot be null". This is a mistake that I have pointed out to you many previous times. Had you ever run this code you would know about it, but of course it is easy to see just by reading the code that it is wrong, if you have the necessary experience. In order to use `StuctureToPtr` we need to allocate some memory. So, let's do that with `IntPtr countPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));`

Comment: With that change, the code runs, but it doesn't do anything useful. There are two further mistakes. The DLL is passed `countPtr`, but this is disconnected from `count`. The call to `StructureToPtr` simply copied the value into the allocated memory. You would need to read it back when the function returned. `count` is never modified and remains at `100` the whole time. Fix that with `count = (int)Marshal.PtrToStructure(countPtr, typeof(int));` after the call to `fillArray` returns.

Comment: The final error is the array. That's a double pointer, `float**`, which we discussed earlier. You pass the address of the first element of an array that you have allocated. But that's missing a level of indirection. Simple inspection of the code in the question reveals how wrong that is. You should use `out IntPtr` and then `Marshal.Copy`.

Comment: Of course, all this can be grossly simplified until it looks like this: `[DllImport(@"Win32Project1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern STATUS fillArray(out IntPtr floatArrayPtr, out int count);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr floatArrayPtr;
            int count;
            STATUS status = fillArray(out floatArrayPtr, out count);
            float[] floatArray = new float[count];
            Marshal.Copy(floatArrayPtr, floatArray, 0, count);
        }`